# Possible to only increment and use a Redis counter and assign to another value in a hash only if that value is not already in the hash?

Tags: redis

It seems like it's not possible to avoid always calling INCR first and always calling HSETNX second, but there are a ton of these and most will never be changing and I'll be needlessly always hitting the server twice. Is that right?

Pseudo example (I know this isn't possible, but I'm asking if there's a pattern to achieve the same effect):

```
LET X = <some unique string>

TRANSACTION/PIPELINE {
    I = INCR GLOBAL COUNTER
    HSETNX(X, I)
}
```

The values are unique and the integers are unique but mapped one-to-one because I need integers rather than strings elsewhere in my situation.

The important things, here, are just making one call and trying to avoid incrementing the counter the 99% of the time that it is not necessary in order to avoid collisions in the future.

Comment: Do you want to increment the counter even if you don't set the value in the hash? To clarify your question, please include code showing the actual sequence of Redis commands you're asking about. In any case, the way to make a sequence of operations atomic in Redis is to use a [transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) (ideally, a Lua script).

Comment: I made that change but I don't know that it adds a lot of value. I don't believe that a transaction will help because I need to pass the result of one call into the second call. As stated, I'm trying to avoid unnecessarily incrementing the value for a couple of different reasons. I've searched and poured through as much documentation as I could find, but I'm not confident that I haven't missed something just around the corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the logic you actually want to implement is:

```
if not HEXISTS(myhash, x):
    i = INCR(counter)
    HSET(myhash, x, i)
```

If you want that to be atomic (and only use a single round trip to the server), write that as a simple Lua script and [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval) it.

Comment: That's a good point.